# Getting sessionId without accessing the session

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my grails application I'm using the spring security core plugin.
Is there any method that returns me a jsessionid for a given user simply by providing username and password

Something like this jsessionid:

```
def myjsessionid = getJessessionidFromUser("username1", "password1")
```

Comment: Do you have access to HTTPSerlvetRequest? If yes - you can access to HTTP session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with grails, but Spring Security itself provides [Concurrent Session Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions) that can maintain a `SessionRegistry`. This registry will contain info about all user sessions that you can query e.g. for getting the sessoin id(s) of a given principal.

Use [`SessionRegistry.getAllSessions()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) to obtain a list of [`SessionInformation`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionInformation.html)s related to a given principal/user, and then `getSessionId()` on those objects.

The concurrency control feature is normally used to limit the number of sessions a user may have, but it can be configured not to enforce such restrictions (just maintain the registry). See more about that in the [Session Management chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/session-mgmt.html#list-authenticated-principals).